# Single Table Inheritance routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have single table inheritance working just fine for my app. I have two user subtypes (Athlete and Company) that inherit the super-type User.

Let's say I am listing all users, and want a link to each user's profile from this list. I want to link to the athletes controller if the type is athlete and the companies controller if the type is company. Is there a standard Rails way to this? Maybe some routing tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can even do that much simpler, Rails recognizes which type of user it has to deal with, so let's say you have the instance variable @user wich can either be an Athlete or a Company, you can just do that

```
= link_to "Profile", @user
```

BAM! Rails magic!

Comment: do i have to have my routes set up in a special way to do this? I get an error: undefined method 'user_path'. Can i call the link something else?

Comment: u have to add map.resources for every resource. I had once companies and people which both are contacts, So I had in my routes.rb: map.resources people
map.resources companies
map.resources contacts

That should do the trick!

Comment: one problem i have with this though, i dont want to use the normal show/:id scheme that map.resource sets up. Instead i want something like `home/:permalink`. I was using `map.connect 'athletes/:action/:permalink', :controller => 'athletes', :action => 'home'`

Comment: Then you should go for Tarscher's solution. But check your routing, it doesn't make sense to tell rails that the action is in the url (via athletes/:action) and then set the action to "home"

Answer (score -3):

```
<% User.find(:all).each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to "user", eval("#{user.type.underscore}_path(user)") %>
<% end %>
```

This will generate a path according to the type of the user (stored in type field). Don't forget to add the type of users to your routes configuration.

I hope this helps.

regards